# Angularjs loading JQuery in partial pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a LAMP website that i am trying to convert to be built on MEAN and I've split the index page into partials so i could have a SPA. 
I am completely new to MEAN but i'm slowly learning and trying things however i'm now stuck on **JQuery slider plugin** that I am using in one of my partials and it does not load any images in the placeholder when the website is ran.
I know that i am supposed to use directives so that JQuery function is loaded after the partial page is loaded into the main page and hence why nothing is being displayed where the slider should be.

This is my partial page that contains the snippet of the slider for a single image (there are 3 of these 'li' blocks at the moment for 3 images):
**home.html**

```
        <div id="pm-slider" class="pm-slider">
            <ul class="pm-slides-container" id="pm_slides_container">

                <li data-thumb="public/app/img/home/slide1a.jpg" class="pmslide_0"><img src="public/app/img/home/slide1.jpg" alt="img01" />

                        <div class="pm-holder">
                            <div class="pm-caption">
                                  <h1>Medical professionals</h1>
                                  <span class="pm-caption-decription">
                                    that you can trust
                                  </span>

                                  <a href="services.html" class="pm-slide-btn">learn more <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
           </div>
```

My **index.html** file contains div ng-view tag where all of home.html should go.

**app.js** contains this code for routing and I know that here should go the .directives function for the JQuery plugin

```
var digiProm = angular.module('digiProm', [
     'ngRoute']);

digiProm.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl:    'public/app/partials/home.html'
        })
        .when('/services', {
            templateUrl:    'public/app/partials/services.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo:     'partials/home.html'
        });
}]);
```

After watching multiple videos as well as tutorials i can't figure out how i should write my directive function to work.. I am trying to work out how to use this type of format

```
  digiProm.directive('slider',  ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
   return {
restrict: 'EA',
templateUrl: '/path/to/template',
link: function(scope, iElement, attrs) {
    //attrs references any attributes on the directive element in html

    //iElement is the actual DOM element of the directive,
    //so you can bind to it with jQuery
    $(iElement).bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        captions: true
    });
   }
};
```

}]);

Is the templateUrl here supposed to be the path to the jquery file for the slideshow? 
What the heck would go inside the link: function(...) ?? This script has been shown as an example on how to use the bxSlider and i'm trying to use a Pulse PM-Slider so not sure what functions i'm supposed to call for it to load after the partial has been loaded...

Any kind of help is much appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the directive is only activating on an element that already exists in another template then you don't need `templateUrl`.

That is used to be able to inject html into an element. in other words a directive can define it's own template

Also the `restrict` is to tell directive whether to look for `E`-an element , or `A` an attribute or `C`- a class.

I suggest you add an attribute since it makes it easier to see later on in the markup

```
<div slider id="pm-slider" class="pm-slider">
```

Then remove `templateUrl` from your directive declaration object.

Also note that when jQuery is included in page before angular.js `iElement` is already a jQuery object so you can just use `iElement.bxslider({....})`

Comment: Thanks for you response. The element already exists in another template so i removed the templateUrl as suggested. I have also added <div slider id="pm-slider" class="pm-slider"> into my home.html template to wrap the image slider, however i still can't get this to work... this is what my directive looks like now:
digiProm.directive('slider',  ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function(scope, iElement, attrs) {
        iElement.PMSlider();
       }
    };
}]);

Comment: is jQuery and plugin being loaded in main page? Any errrors? Can you see anything when you run `console.log('something')` in link of directive?

Comment: Thanks for the console.log idea, after experimenting a little i realised that i had to put the <div slider id="pm-slider" class="pm-slider"> into my index.html ng-view wrapper and not inside my home.html page because its only a partial page... Slider is still not working, but i will keep trying and hopefully get something. Would it be at all possible to contact you directly for some short advice if you don't mind? :)

Comment: leave another comment or start a new question

Comment: Do you have any idea why it now displays every image, one below the other on my main page instead of being a slider?

Comment: Not without being able to inspect in browser dev tools. Sounds like some css is missing ... or markup used doesn't match plugin specs